# Count how many rows have the same value in msql database

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to update a field nr in the database:

I have: Example data…

table ring

```
ID     ri             mr        nr
1                      a         0
2      a               b         0
3      a               c         0
4                      d         0
5      b               e         0
6      e               f         0
```

I need a query that gives this result to sum where sum count how many times value from mr apear in ri and update nr whit this value

Result shoud be like this

```
ID     ri             mr        nr
1                      a         2
2      a               b         1
3      a               c         0
4                      d         0
5      b               e         1
6      e               f         0
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the expected `nr` column in your output.

Comment: nr exist and is  =  with  how many times mr apears in ri  for each ID like  for id 1  mr=a is in ri  2 times so for ID=1 nr =2.  And i need to update nr with this value 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE `ring` a, (SELECT ri,COUNT(*) cnt 
               FROM `ring` 
           GROUP BY ri) b

SET a.nr = b.cnt
 WHERE mr = b.ri");

this work for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` and `group by`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(cnt, 0) as nr
from t left join
     (select mr, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by mr
     ) tt
     on t.mr = tt.mr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query to count the number of times that `ri` matches `mr`

```
select 
  t.*, 
  (select count(*) from tablename where ri = t.mr) nr
from tablename t
```

If the column nr exists and you want to update it:

```
update tablename t
set t.nr = (select count(*) from tablename where ri = t.mr)
```

If you use Mysql then this will do:

```
update tablename t
inner join (
  select mr, (select count(*) from tablename where ri = t.mr) counter from tablename t
) tt on tt.mr = t.mr
set t.nr = tt.counter
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p4sme4KJQ3LvwEb6bTDNY3/0)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For update use

```
update tablename set nr = (select count(*) from tablename where ri = mr)
```